# Convert degree to radians in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a latitude and longitude in degrees and I want to convert these into radians. How can I do that?

P.S. I am using sphinx search engine and it requires values in radians

Comment: While this does involve simple math, I believe it is still valid to ask if this feature is implemented in Ruby's standard libraries.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just the same way you convert degrees to radians in real life:

```
radians = degrees * Math::PI / 180
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 360 degrees and 2 pi radians in a circle. So to convert degrees to radians, divide by 360 and multiply by 2 * pi (approx. 6.28).

Or equivalently, divide by 180 and multiply by pi.